# Getting segmentation fault while comparing the \n of a string that red by fgets() in C language

Tags: segmentation-fault, newline, fgets

I am writing a program to reverse the words in a string, i.e., `"abc def"` to `"def abc"`.

I read the input using `fgets()`. I am using:

```
for(j = i;((buff[i] != ' ') || (buff[i] != '\n'));i++ );
```

to identify the space or end of line.

But I am ending up with a segmentation fault.

With checking for space alone, everything is working fine.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
((buff[i] != ' ') || (buff[i] != '\n'))
```

This means "keep going while the character is not a space ***or*** is not a newline".

Since a character can never be both a space and a newline at the same time, at least *one* of those sub-conditions will always be true. Lets take a few examples:

```
value    (value != ' ')  (value != '\n')  or'ed result
-------  --------------  ---------------  ------------
space        false           true             true
newline      true            false            true
'A'          true            true             true
```

Hence you have an infinite loop which is almost certainly what's causing your problem.

I suggest you replace the `||` with the more correct `&&` as in "keep going while the character is both not a space ***and*** not a newline":

```
value    (value != ' ')  (value != '\n')  and'ed result
-------  --------------  ---------------  -------------
space        false           true             false
newline      true            false            false
'A'          true            true             true
```

Comment: Replaced with the &&, it worked.Thank you for the detailed explanation.